# Print error while creating a sudoku solver in c++

Tags: c++, recursion, backtracking, sudoku

The print function in the code prints the original board and not the solution, whereas the solver function prints the solution which suggests that the original board has been updated in place. I passed the board by reference to the functions as you can see, so why is not the original board getting updated after calling the print function?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int n = 9;

void print(vector<vector<char>>& board){
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            cout << board[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void solver(int x, int y, vector<vector<char>>& board, map< pair<int, int>, map<int, int> >& grid, vector<map<int, int>> row,vector<map<int, int>>& col){

    if(x == 9){
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                cout << board[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        return;
    }

    if(y == 9){
        solver(x + 1, 0, board, grid, row, col);
        return;
    }

    if(board[x][y] != '.'){
        solver(x, y + 1, board, grid, row,  col);
        return;
    }

    for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
        if(!grid[{x/3, y/3}][i] && !row[x][i] && !col[y][i]){
            board[x][y] = i + '0';
            grid[{x/3, y/3}][i] = 1;
            row[x][i] = 1;
            col[y][i] = 1;
            solver(x, y + 1, board, grid, row, col);
            board[x][y] = '.';
            grid[{x/3, y/3}][i] = 0;
            row[x][i] = 0;
            col[y][i] = 0;
        }
    }

}

void solveSudoku(vector<vector<char>>& board) {
    //int n = board.size();
    vector< map<int, int> > row(n);
    vector< map<int, int> > col(n);
    map< pair<int, int>, map<int, int> > grid;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if(board[i][j] != '.'){
                row[i][board[i][j] - '0'] = 1;
                col[j][board[i][j] - '0'] = 1;
                grid[{i/3, j/3}][board[i][j] - '0'] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    solver(0, 0, board, grid, row, col);
}

int main(){

    vector<vector<char>> board =
    {{ '5','3','.','.','7','.','.','.','.'},
     {'6','.','.','1','9','5','.','.','.'},
     {'.','9','8','.','.','.','.','6','.'},
     {'8','.','.','.','6','.','.','.','3'},
     {'4','.','.','8','.','3','.','.','1'},
     {'7','.','.','.','2','.','.','.','6'},
     {'.','6','.','.','.','.','2','8','.'},
     {'.','.','.','4','1','9','.','.','5'},
     {'.','.','.','.','8','.','.','7','9'}};
    solveSudoku(board);
    cout << endl;
    print(board);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the only place I found where you modify the board is `board[x][y] = i + '0';` and some lines below you reset that via `board[x][y] = '.';`

Comment: Look carefully how `row` passed to the solver.

Comment: The line `board[x][y] = '.';` is the reason for the behavior you are seeing. I didn't follow the solver logic carefully to figure out whether that is essential for the solver.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number That is the backtracking logic. But in the end the board is getting printed finally in the solver function as it is the edge case and then return. So why will the board(now solution) get updated?

Comment: @S.M. Still did not fix the issue.

Comment: @RSahu That is the backtracking logic. But in the end the board is getting printed finally in the solver function as it is the edge case and then return. So why will the board(now solution) get updated back to original input? Please reply if u got me

Comment: @Ashwin, add a line `std::cout << "Changing board[x][y] to '.'" << std::endl;` before that line to help you track down when that line gets executed and why the state of `board` is getting reset.

Comment: @Ashwin i dont fully understand the code or the backtracking but I am quite certain that by the time `solver` returns, whatever has been set by `board[x][y] = i + '0';` will be reset by `board[x][y] = '.';`. There is some recursion and what not in between, but try to consider only the state of `board` when `solver` returns

Comment: @RSahu can u plz run the code by urself, as its really complex to understand. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first call to `solver` is:

```
solver(0, 0, board, grid, row, col);
```

Because `board[0][0]` is not `'.'` that first call is only

```
if(board[x][y] != '.'){
    solver(x, y + 1, board, grid, row,  col);
    return;
}
```

That is: it calls `solver(0,1,board,grid,row,col)`. Then `board[0][1]` is `'.'`, and `x` is not `9` and `y` is not `9` and that call executes:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
    if(!grid[{x/3, y/3}][i] && !row[x][i] && !col[y][i]){
        board[x][y] = i + '0';
        grid[{x/3, y/3}][i] = 1;
        row[x][i] = 1;
        col[y][i] = 1;
        solver(x, y + 1, board, grid, row, col);
        board[x][y] = '.';
        grid[{x/3, y/3}][i] = 0;
        row[x][i] = 0;
        col[y][i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Hence if we inline the first two calls, we can replace `solver(0, 0, board, grid, row, col);` with the above to get:

```
void solveSudoku(vector<vector<char>>& board) {
    //int n = board.size();
    vector< map<int, int> > row(n);
    vector< map<int, int> > col(n);
    map< pair<int, int>, map<int, int> > grid;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if(board[i][j] != '.'){
                row[i][board[i][j] - '0'] = 1;
                col[j][board[i][j] - '0'] = 1;
                grid[{i/3, j/3}][board[i][j] - '0'] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    size_t x = 0; 
    size_t y = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
        if(!grid[{x/3, y/3}][i] && !row[x][i] && !col[y][i]){
            board[x][y] = i + '0';
            grid[{x/3, y/3}][i] = 1;
            row[x][i] = 1;
            col[y][i] = 1;
            solver(x, y + 1, board, grid, row, col);
            board[x][y] = '.';
            grid[{x/3, y/3}][i] = 0;
            row[x][i] = 0;
            col[y][i] = 0;
        }
    }    
}
```

Here `board[0][1]` is assigned a `i + '0';` then the recursion happens and after that `board[0][1]` is reset to `'.'`. Same line of reasoning can be applied when going deeper the call chain of the recursion. Whenever you assign something to `board[x][y]` it will be reset before `solver` returns to `solveSudoku`. You only reach `x == 9` and print the updated board when you are the "bottom of the recursion" but you only return to `sudokuSolver` via the path that executes `board[x][y] = '.';`.

Don't know how to explain better, perhaps it is more convincing for you to see it live with a debugger.